# How to do following XML config in to Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am converting XML config into Java config. I am not sure How to do the following XML config. Please help. Thanks

```
  <beans profile="!cloud">
    <bean name="remotingURL" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${web.remoting.url.base}/#{applicationID.toLowerCase()}server/remoting" />
    </bean>
</beans>
<beans profile="cloud">
    <bean name="remotingURL" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${web.remoting.url.base}/remoting" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Configuration Class for each Profile you need. Then use @Value to inject the values from your properties.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudConfig{
@Bean
public String remoteURL(@Value("${web.remoting.url.base}") String url) {
return url + "/remoting";
}
}

@Configuration
@Profile("!cloud")
public class RemoteConfig{
@Bean
public String remoteURL(@Value("${web.remoting.url.base}") String url, String applicationID) {
return url + "/" + applicationId.toLowerCase() + "server/remoting";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I used your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
  public class Test {

  @Bean(name = "remotingURL")
  @Conditional(NotCloud.class)
  public String remotingURL1(@Value("${web.remoting.url.base}") String url, String applicationID) {
    return new String(url + "/" + applicationId.toLowerCase() + "server/remoting");
  }

  @Bean(name = "remotingURL")
  @Conditional(Cloud.class)
  public String remotingURL2(@Value("${web.remoting.url.base}") String url) {
    return new String(url + "/remoting");
  }


    }        

     @Override
     public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
                return !context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("cloud");
              }
            }



    public class NotCloud implements Condition {

      @Override
      public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return !context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("cloud");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Rakesh, What is the benefit of using @Conditional instead of @Profile?

Comment: Conditional is introduced from spring 4.0 onwards allowing developers to define conditional checking. Example: We could use profile to load application based on the environment and Conditional can be used operating system level (Windows/Linux) or Conditions Bean’s Method’s Annotations or Conditions based on a Bean object are present in the Spring Application context. In this solution, I have answered rather than creating two configuration classes (one for each profile) I preferred to keep code minimal but the same can be achieved using the answer provided by @martin-baumgartner as well.